# Network issues with huwaei USB 3G modem

Tags: networking

I have a raspberry pi 2 plugged into a (Vodafone New Zealand) 3G usb modem.  It's a huwaei one.  I have managed to get it working correctly, (I even [wrote a rubygem](https://github.com/patrickdavey/vodem_sms) to help with reading SMS's off the modem, and for 'connecting' and 'disconnecting' from the internet).  However, I'm having real issues with the DNS and I was wondering if anyone might be able to help.

I have tried restarting it (with and without the usb modem attached) and various configurations in the `/etc/network/interfaces` mostly without joy.  What I want is a bombproof way to restart it correctly, as the idea is to use the pi for remote monitoring of a water quality study site, and I want to be able to restart it remotely and make sure the 3G comes up correctly.

Some things which may help:

*network interfaces*
I tried both static and dynamic, even specifying the nameservers.

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

auto usb0
iface usb0 inet static  
address 192.168.9.136
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.9.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

**dynamic interfaces

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

allow-hotplug usb0
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet dhcp
```

if I restart the modem with the usb stick plugged in, this is my `route -n` and `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:26:70:3c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:0c:e7:0b:01:02  
      inet addr:192.168.9.136  Bcast:192.168.9.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:200 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:196 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:13780 (13.4 KiB)  TX bytes:16124 (15.7 KiB)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.9.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.9.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0
```

if I start without the usb modem plugged in

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:26:70:3c  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

This is the ping to google (honestly can't remember which of the variations this was on

```
PING google.com (192.168.59.5) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- google.com ping statistics ---
18 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 17001ms
```

The *slightly* odd thing I noticed, was that on one of the pings, it started off pinging 192.168.9.1 , I think, certainly it was the gateway ip address.

Anyway, somewhat tearing my hair out here.. I feel like I'm 99% of the way there, but could really use a hand getting over the line!  Thanks.

Finally, here is a (bad) traceroute to google.com if that helps

```
 traceroute to google.com (192.168.59.5), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.9.1 (192.168.9.1)  0.909 ms  1.599 ms  1.792 ms
 2  172.27.74.44 (172.27.74.44)  1141.241 ms  1143.081 ms  1143.172 ms
  3  172.27.66.219 (172.27.66.219)  1243.072 ms  1243.110 ms  1243.119 ms
  4  172.27.87.69 (172.27.87.69)  1275.568 ms  1275.273 ms  1242.989 ms
  5  172.27.87.70 (172.27.87.70)  1275.574 ms  1275.299 ms  1275.616 ms
  6  203.109.129.190 (203.109.129.190)  1275.370 ms  1242.945 ms  1242.237 ms
  7  203.109.129.189 (203.109.129.189)  1209.486 ms  105.834 ms  105.253 ms
  8  203.109.180.225 (203.109.180.225)  105.353 ms  133.821 ms  147.434 ms
  9  203.109.180.226 (203.109.180.226)  149.173 ms  147.342 ms  147.348 ms
 10  192.168.59.254 (192.168.59.254)  146.812 ms  82.653 ms  126.443 ms
 11  * * *
```

(just stars after 11->30)

Hmmmm, what's interesting is that if you ping one of the 203 addresses (e.g. http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=ptr%3a203.109.180.226&run=toolpage )... is is actually a vodafone ip address.  Why (the hell) it's then coming back with 192.168.59.254 is most strange (to me anyway)

finally ;)

If I unplug the 3G modem from the pi, plug it into my PC (running Ubuntu) it *can* ping google.. this is the traceroute I get.

```
  1  192.168.9.1 (192.168.9.1)  1.804 ms  2.166 ms  2.531 ms
  2  172.27.74.44 (172.27.74.44)  73.779 ms  73.889 ms  73.996 ms
  3  172.27.66.220 (172.27.66.220)  83.737 ms  83.979 ms  93.473 ms
  4  172.27.87.69 (172.27.87.69)  113.967 ms  113.959 ms  113.697 ms
  5  172.27.87.70 (172.27.87.70)  123.940 ms  123.683 ms  124.045 ms
  6  vl628.akl-grafton-bdr1.ihug.net (203.109.129.190)  124.164 ms  90.028 ms  89.777 ms
  7  fa0-0-628.pmr-tcl-core1.ihug.net (203.109.129.189)  89.883 ms  89.994 ms  89.611 ms
  8  be8-188.ppnzftc02.akl.vf.net.nz.180.109.203.in-addr.arpa (203.109.180.225)  90.218 ms  90.328 ms  99.321 ms
  9  UNASSIGNED.vf.net.nz (203.109.180.207)  99.562 ms  99.803 ms  109.548 ms
 10  * * *
```

I really don't get it!

Answer (score 1):

Turned out (still don't quite know why) the `/etc/resolve.conf` had cached DNS settings from when eth0 was active, and it *didn't* update them for the usb0 ethernet.

Fix was to manually create `/etc/resolve.conf` and put in the nameserver details I wanted (I just used googles)  So, all working now & happy days.